# Scikit-Learn: Custom Loss Function for GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, loss-function

I'm working on a Kaggle competition (https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques#evaluation) and it states that my model will be evaluated by:

```
Submissions are evaluated on Root-Mean-Squared-Error (RMSE) between the logarithm of the predicted value and the logarithm of the observed sales price. (Taking logs means that errors in predicting expensive houses and cheap houses will affect the result equally.)
```

I couldn't find this in the docs (it's basically `RMSE(log(truth), log(prediction)`), so I went about writing a custom scorer:

```
def custom_loss(truth, preds):
    truth_logs = np.log(truth)
    print(truth_logs)
    preds_logs = np.log(preds)
    numerator = np.sum(np.square(truth_logs - preds_logs))
    return np.sum(np.sqrt(numerator / len(truth)))

custom_scorer = make_scorer(custom_loss, greater_is_better=False)
```

Two questions:

1) Should my custom loss function return a numpy array of scores (one for each (truth, prediction) pair?  Or should it be the total loss over those (truth, prediction) pairs, returning a single number?

I looked into the docs but they weren't super helpful re: what my custom loss function should return.

2) When I run:

```
xgb_model = xgb.XGBRegressor()
params = {"max_depth": [3, 4], "learning_rate": [0.05],
         "n_estimators": [1000, 2000], "n_jobs": [8], "subsample": [0.8], "random_state": [42]}
grid_search_cv = GridSearchCV(xgb_model, params, scoring=custom_scorer,
                             n_jobs=8, cv=KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=42), verbose=2)

grid_search_cv.fit(X, y)

grid_search_cv.best_score_
```

I get back:

```
-0.12137097567803554
```

which is very surprising.  Given that my loss function is taking `RMSE(log(truth) - log(prediction))`, I shouldn't be able to have a negative `best_score_`.

Any idea why it's negative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) You should return a single number as loss, not array. GridSearchCV will sort the params accroding to the results of this scorer.

By the way instead of defining a custom metric, you can use [`mean_squared_log_error`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#mean-squared-logarithmic-error), which does what you want.

2) Why does it return negative? - Without your actual data and complete code we cant say.

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful with the notation.

There are 2 levels of optimization here:

1. The loss function optimized when the `XGBRegressor` is fitted to the data.
2. The scoring function that is optimized during the grid search.

I prefer calling the second *scoring* function instead of *loss* function, since loss function usually refers to a term that is subject to optimization during the model fitting process itself.
However, your custom function only specifies 2. whilst leaving 1. untouched. In case you want to change the loss function of `XGBRegressor` see [here](https://dask-ml.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/generated/dask_ml.xgboost.XGBRegressor.html). Most regression models have several criteria from which you can choose such as `mean_square_error` or `mean_absolute_error`.

Note, that passing customized loss functions is not supported at the moment (see reasons [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3071) and [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1701)).

Answer (score 0):

The make_scorer function sign flips if greater_is_better is False